# Create stacking elements on mobile view without any media-query for responsive email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've not been able to achieve it because media-query is not supported on Gmail IMAP which my client uses.

How do I achieve the column layout on the top to be like the stacking elements below it without any media query?

What is the workaround of it?

I can't find any workaround

The column layout should be shown when in desktop mode.

```html
<table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 10px 0;">
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px 10px 0;">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
                   style="border-collapse: collapse;background: #FFFFFF;border-radius: 10px;">
              <tr>
                <td height="45" style="padding: 65px 45px;">
                  <div class="hide-for-small">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 40px">
                      <tr style="height: 60px">
                        <td style="vertical-align:top; width: 54px;">
                          <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/178/595/png-transparent-user-profile-computer-icons-login-user-avatars.png" width="25px" height="auto" style="width: 25px !important" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:top; width: 45%;">
                          <span style="display: block; font-size: 11px; color: #AFC2CE; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 0.77px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 7px;">
                            text
                          </span>

                          <span style="display: block; font-size:14px; color: #003A60; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; word-break: break-all;padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
text
                          </span>
                        </td>

                        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 54px;">
                          <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/178/595/png-transparent-user-profile-computer-icons-login-user-avatars.png" width="25px" height="auto" style="width: 25px !important" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                          <div style="display: block; font-size: 11px; color: #AFC2CE; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 0.77px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 7px;">
                            text
                          </div>

                          <span style="display: block; font-size:14px; color: #003A60; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">
                            text
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 54px;">
                          <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/178/595/png-transparent-user-profile-computer-icons-login-user-avatars.png" width="25px" height="auto" style="width: 25px !important" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:top; width: 45%;">
                          <span style="display: block; font-size: 11px; color: #AFC2CE; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 0.77px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 7px;">
                            text
                          </span>

                          <span style="display: block; font-size:14px; color: #003A60; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; word-break: break-all;padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                            text
                          </span>
                        </td>

                        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 54px;">
                          <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/178/595/png-transparent-user-profile-computer-icons-login-user-avatars.png" width="25px" height="auto" style="width: 25px !important" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                          <span style="display: block; font-size: 11px; color: #AFC2CE; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 0.77px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 7px;">
                            text
                          </span>

                          <span style="display: block; font-size:14px; color: #003A60; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">
                            text
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="hide-for-large">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 40px">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/178/595/png-transparent-user-profile-computer-icons-login-user-avatars.png" width="25px" height="auto" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 25px !important" />
                          <span style="font-size: 11px; color: #AFC2CE; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 0.77px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-left: 10px">
                            stacking elements start
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <span style="font-size:14px; color: #003A60; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; word-break: break-all;padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr style="height: 30px;"></tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/178/595/png-transparent-user-profile-computer-icons-login-user-avatars.png" width="25px" height="auto" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 25px !important" />
                          <span style="font-size: 11px; color: #AFC2CE; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 0.77px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-left: 10px">
                            text
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <span style="font-size:14px; color: #003A60; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; word-break: break-all;padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr style="height: 30px;"></tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/178/595/png-transparent-user-profile-computer-icons-login-user-avatars.png" width="25px" height="auto" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 25px !important" />
                          <span style="font-size: 11px; color: #AFC2CE; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 0.77px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-left: 10px">
                            text
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <span style="font-size:14px; color: #003A60; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; word-break: break-all;padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 30px;"></tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/178/595/png-transparent-user-profile-computer-icons-login-user-avatars.png" width="25px" height="auto" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 25px !important" />
                          <span style="font-size: 11px; color: #AFC2CE; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 0.77px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-left: 10px">
                            text
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 5px;"></tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <span style="font-size:14px; color: #003A60; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; word-break: break-all;padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive email HTML without media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995588/responsive-email-html-without-media-queries)

Comment: This has been answered many times, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336628/how-to-stack-3-fluid-responsive-columns-without-media-queries and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135988/responsive-html-email-template-without-using-css-media-queries

Comment: would you replicate it on my case and fix this issue once and for all?

Comment: No because your code needs to be started from scratch. You need to use those other answers to start again.